# Making the width of a colorbox fit raggedright text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, color

I'm trying to recreate something like this as a parttitle:
[image: this]

This is a MWE of what I've got so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt,extrafontsizes,twoside,onecolumn,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}

\title{Main}

\def\titsize{\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont}
\def\parttitsize{\fontsize{27}{46}\selectfont}

\def\stripheight(#1,#2){\vrule height #1 depth #2 width 0pt}

\renewcommand{\partname}{\thetitle}
\renewcommand{\partnamefont}{\color{white}\titsize\raggedright\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\partnamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\partnumfont}{\color{white}\titsize\raggedright\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\parttitlefont}{\color{white}\parttitsize\raggedright\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\printpartname}{%
    \hspace{-10pt}\colorbox{orange}{%
        \parbox{\textwidth}{%
            \hspace{10pt}%
            \stripheight(55pt,10pt)\partnamefont\partname\quad\thepart%
            \hspace{10pt}%
        }
    }%
}
\renewcommand{\printpartnum}{}
\renewcommand{\printparttitle}[1]{%
    \hspace{-10pt}\colorbox{orange}{%
        \parbox{\textwidth}{
            \hspace{10pt}%
            \parttitlefont{\stripheight(30pt,10pt)#1}%
            \hspace{10pt}%
        }%
    }%
}


\begin{document}
    \part{Long parttitle which wraps around}
\end{document}
```

There are several problems with this:

- because of `\parbox{\textwidth}` the box is too wide. I've tried changing it to `\parbox{\width}` but that didn't work.
- there should be a colored 'margin' of about 10 pt around the text. I did that with the `\partname` using `\hspace{10pt}` and a kind of `\strut` I define with `\stripheight`, but again that doesn't really work when there are multiple lines, as in the `\parttitle`.
- the lines should be separate from each other. This can be white, because I'm working with a white background. So maybe it could be as simple as drawing a white line, but I really have no idea where to start.

Comment: Use `tcolorbox` with a `\tcbox` -- it will have the box width exactly to the content (plus some margin spacings)

Comment: for titles you normally want manual linebreaking anyway in which case it is easy `\setlength\fboxsep{10pt} \colorbox{yellow}{Become}\\\colorbox{yellow}{Something}\\\colorbox{yellow}{...}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer that would work for a single line, but the width of every line of a multiline title would be the same.

@DavidCarlisle That's true but the text comes from a single `\part{long title which wraps around}` command (because I also want it in the toc) so it can't be broken up easily

Comment: @titto: I did not say it's easy with `tcolorbox`. Nobody forces you to use it ;-)

Comment: You could use three boxes ...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer as I said the text comes from a single `\part{...}` command, so it can't really be broken down. But I think I found the start of a solution using `\hl{...}` from the [`soul`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/soul) package.

Comment: Did you look into the `soul` package? It seems that you can somehow combine it with `tikz` so that you could maybe enhance the boxish style of `soul`’s highlighting ... like `\renewcommand{\printparttitle}[1]{\sethlcolor{orange}\raggedright{\color{white}\parttitsize\hl{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}}` as a starting point

Comment: I see text. I see yellow bars behind text. I see a picture behind all of it. What exactly do you need? I can see why colored lines on a colourful (image) background, but i cannot understand why to have colored lines on a non-existent background. Just have the text, which is the important thing, your message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own answer is already a good start. I didn’t know about the package `soulpos` before! This makes things way easier! You could use the following code then (your code with some minor simplifications):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage{soulpos,xcolor,calc}

\def\titsize{\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont}
\def\parttitsize{\fontsize{27}{44}\selectfont}

\ulposdef{\myhl}{%
  \hskip-5mm\mbox{%
    \textcolor{orange}{\rule[-.9ex]{\ulwidth+10mm}{3.5ex}}%
  }\hskip5mm%
}

\renewcommand{\partnamefont}{\color{white}\titsize\raggedright\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\partnumfont}{\color{white}\titsize\raggedright\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\parttitlefont}{\color{white}\parttitsize\raggedright\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\printpartname}{%
  \partnamefont{\myhl{\thetitle\partnamenum\thepart}}%
}
\renewcommand{\printpartnum}{}
\renewcommand{\printparttitle}[1]{%
  \parttitlefont{\myhl{#1}}%
}

\title{Main}

\begin{document}
  \part{Long parttitle which wraps around twice}
\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

I used absolute lengths (mm instead of em) for the padding, in order to have equal left and right paddings for different text sizes.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer, I can't find a way to do what I want.

First I tried using the [`soul`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/soul) package (commented out in the MWE below). It made a nice box, but I couldn't extend the box to the left or to the right. (I could, using `\setuloverlap`, but because the value was too high it printed over some letters, so that didn't work)

Then I tried using the [`soulpos`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/soulpos) package. This allowed me to extend the box to the left of the first line and to the right of the last line, but I couldn't get it to just make wider boxes.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt,extrafontsizes,twoside,onecolumn,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{soulpos}

\title{Main}

\def\titsize{\fontsize{60}{70}\selectfont}
\def\parttitsize{\fontsize{27}{44}\selectfont}

%\makeatletter
%\def\SOUL@hlpreamble{%
%   \setul{}{3.5ex}%
%   \dimen@\SOUL@ulthickness
%   \dimen@i=-.8ex
%   \advance\dimen@i-.5\dimen@
%   \edef\SOUL@uldepth{\the\dimen@i}%
%   \let\SOUL@ulcolor\SOUL@hlcolor
%   \SOUL@ulpreamble
%}
%\makeatother

\ulposdef{\myhl}[xoffset=.5em]{%
    \mbox{%
        \color{orange}%
        \rule[-.9ex]{\ulwidth}{3.5ex}}}

\renewcommand{\partnamefont}{\color{white}\titsize\raggedright\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\partnumfont}{\color{white}\titsize\raggedright\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\parttitlefont}{\color{white}\parttitsize\raggedright\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\printpartname}{%
%   \setuloverlap{20pt}
%   \sethlcolor{orange}%
    \partnamefont{\myhl{\thetitle\partnamenum\thepart}}%
}
\renewcommand{\printpartnum}{}
\renewcommand{\printparttitle}[1]{%
%   \setuloverlap{12pt}
%   \sethlcolor{orange}%
    \parttitlefont{\myhl{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
    \part{Long parttitle which wraps around twice}
\end{document}
```